# Android Check if connection was interrupted

Tags: android

My app needs to download a database from the internet. This is done in an `AsyncTask` so when the database is being downloaded it't is being shown a `Progress Dialog`.

This is the code for the database download:

```
    public void downloadDB(String dbFile, String dbFileName) {
        int count;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(dbFile);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();

            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(ctx.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/" + dbFileName);

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            output.flush();

            output.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I'm doing some tests and when the database is being downloaded I turn off the internet connection. The problem is that the `Progress Dialog` doesn't terminate (it's in an infinite loop). I was expecting that after turning off the internet, there would be the `IOException`, the function returned to the `doInBackground` method of `AsyncTask` and executed the `onPostExecute` method where I dismiss the `Progress Dialog`.

The strange thing is that if I have my phone disconnected from the computer, the progress dialog is never dismissed, the same thing if I'm running the app with phone connected to computer and looking at the log cat. If I enter debug mode, the `downloadDB` ends and is returned to the caller and then, the progress dialog is dismissed.

What can I do to return from the `downloadDB` function when the network is turned off?

Comment: if u want to dismiss progress dialog only then u have to use dialog.setclickable(true);

Comment: I want that the function terminates and then the dialog is dismissed by itself I would see if the download was ok and then proceed accordingly

Comment: <http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#setReadTimeout%28int%29>

Comment: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835867/how-to-stay-in-an-activity-if-the-internet-connection-is-lost-in-between-an-asyn>

Comment: @HCD thanks but did not understand what was meant to see